# Знак рубля в контенте псевдокласса

Tags: html

Как известно,что-бы написать на странице знак рубля используется его html код: `&#8381;`, соответственно получаем: ₽, но когда вставляешь его в контент псевдоэлемента отображается на странице код знака, вместо него самого.
Как быть?

Comment: взять и в контент впихнуть сам знак `₽` )

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, каким образом?

Comment: Выдели знак который нарисован сейчас - ctrl+c, ctrl+v

Comment: Обоже, этот рубль-на-костылях таки стал _официальным_ знаком рубля?

Comment: @VladD, ты просто завидуешь :₽

Comment: @Grundy: Да, мне не хватает официального знака дойчмарки :)

Comment: @VladD, судя по википедии у нее были `D` и `DM` :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вставить unicode код символа например. У знака рубля код `20BD`.

```css
.test:after { 
     content:"\20BD"; 
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
   1000
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Можно указать не `&#8381;`, а его код в *UNICODE*:

```css
p:after {
    content: "\20BD";
}
```

```html
<p>100</p>
```

Или же просто вставить требуемый символ:

```css
p:after {
    content: "₽";
}
```

```html
<p>100</p>
```